# Any major difference between Infinispan and Ehcache with JGroups replication

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, infinispan

I was doing a proof of concept on caching solutions. My requirement is to replicate the cache on different servers (cache cluster).

After some effort, I shortlisted 2 caching solutions:

1. Ehcache with JGroups as replication strategy
2. Infinispan

Is there any major difference between these 2 caching solutions? I am really confused because Infinispan also uses JGroups internally.

Is there any major advantage/disadvantage/overload in any of these caching solutions over the other? At least for a small cluster.